Fine-Tuning with Keras models from_preset
I am trying to fine-tune a DebertaV3 model using the new keras_nlp models from_preset and running into an strange error that I cannot quite understand.
Th error is indicating the "metric" is not built, but I am using a standard metric. The result is the same if I just use metrics=['accuracy'].
NOTE:
model.metrics (after compile) shows the following unusual output:
[<Mean name=loss>, <Mean name=loss>, <CompileMetrics name=compile_metrics>, <CompileMetrics name=compile_metrics>]

Note the double CompileMetrics. I think there should only be one. But why two?
The raw data is:

list of texts from a essays.
scores of the essays (ranging from 1 - 6)

TensorFlow: 2.15.0
Keras: 3.3.3
keras-nlp:  0.11.1

preprocessor = keras_nlp.models.DebertaV3Preprocessor.from_preset('deberta_v3_base_en', sequence_length=512)

classifier = keras_nlp.models.DebertaV3Classifier.from_preset('deberta_v3_base_en',
                                          preprocessor=None,
                                          load_weights=True,
                                          num_classes=6)

# Train Data
train_texts = train_df.full_text.tolist()  # Extract training texts
train_labels = train_df.score.tolist()  # Extract training labels
train_encoded = preprocessor(train_texts)
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_encoded, train_labels))
train_ds = train_ds.batch(CFG.batch_size).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

# Valid Data
valid_texts = valid_df.full_text.tolist()  # Extract validation texts
valid_labels = valid_df.score.tolist()  # Extract validation labels
valid_encoded = preprocessor(valid_texts)
valid_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((valid_encoded, valid_labels))
valid_ds = valid_ds.batch(CFG.batch_size).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

# Model creation
classifier.backbone.trainable = False

inputs = classifier.input
#input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(512,), dtype=tf.int32)

logits = classifier(inputs)
outputs = keras.layers.Activation("softmax")(logits)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name='model_' + CFG.preset)

# Set the head of the model as trainable
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True

model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.AdamW(5e-5),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='accuracy')],
    jit_compile=True,
)

model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=valid_ds,
    epochs=5
)

Model: "model_deberta_v3_base_en"
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)        ┃ Output Shape      ┃    Param # ┃ Connected to      ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ padding_mask        │ (None, None)      │          0 │ -                 │
│ (InputLayer)        │                   │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ token_ids           │ (None, None)      │          0 │ -                 │
│ (InputLayer)        │                   │            │                   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ deberta_v3_classif… │ (None, 6)         │ 184,426,7… │ padding_mask[0][… │
│ (DebertaV3Classifi… │                   │            │ token_ids[0][0]   │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ activation_2        │ (None, 6)         │          0 │ deberta_v3_class… │
│ (Activation)        │                   │            │                   │
└─────────────────────┴───────────────────┴────────────┴───────────────────┘
 Total params: 184,426,758 (703.53 MB)
 Trainable params: 595,206 (2.27 MB)
 Non-trainable params: 183,831,552 (701.26 MB)

Error:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[46], line 1
----> 1 model.fit(
      2     train_ds,
      3     validation_data=valid_ds,
      4     epochs=CFG.epochs,
      5     #callbacks=[lr_cb, ckpt_cb]
      6 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/trainers/compile_utils.py:356, in CompileMetrics.result(self)
    354 def result(self):
    355     if not self.built:
--> 356         raise ValueError(
    357             "Cannot get result() since the metric has not yet been built."
    358         )
    359     results = {}
    360     unique_name_counters = {}

ValueError: Cannot get result() since the metric has not yet been built.


It turns out what I was trying to do was fine tune a model before transfer learning process, which led to metric has not been built yet.
The initial classifier should first be put through all or part of the new dataset with the pretrained weights and then fine-tuned with additional model layers.
Once the initial classifier.fit() is processed, the fine tuning step works fine.
specific steps can be found here.
